# Angular Ngoninit getting called everytime while routing

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have one component Details where the routes for other child components is there. What is happening is that when I route to any other child component then the onint of the Details is getting called.

For Example- example.com/details/123123123/profile is my current route

I am navigating to example.com/details/12312331/pastappointment

then the NgOnInit of Details is getting called. Which is calling all the apis that I don't want.

Comment: Are you using router-outlet to project the child components? Do you only replace parts of the URL? You need to give us more information as to how you structured the routing. Maybe a stackblitz?

Comment: i use child as-
<li routerLink="patient-info" routerLinkActive="active"><a class="ac-an">Profile</a></li>
          <li routerLink="medical-history" routerLinkActive="active"><a class="ac-an">Medical History</a></li>

Comment: Can you please share code of your routing file? Also, have you used router outlet?

Comment: path: 'patient-details/:id', component: PatientDetailsComponent,
      children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'patient-dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'patient-dashboard', component: PatientDashboardComponent },
        {
          path: 'patient-info', component: PatientInfoComponent,
          }
        { path: 'medical-history', component: MedicalHistoryComponent },

Comment: No i am not using router outlet

Comment: Put <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the PatientDetailsComponent's html file

Comment: i used the router outlet. still same thing. One thing is there, if I reload the page then everything is working fine, but not when I first redirect to patient details

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

inside your Details component.

Comment: i used the router outlet. still same thing. One thing is there, if I reload the page then everything is working fine, but not when I first redirect to patient details

Comment: Could you share the routes file, or the routes where you redirect to patient details?

Comment: my routing....
path: 'patient-details/:id', component: PatientDetailsComponent,
      children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'patient-dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'patient-dashboard', component: PatientDashboardComponent },
        {
          path: 'patient-info', component: PatientInfoComponent,
        { path: 'medical-history', component: MedicalHistoryComponent },
        { path: 'medical-records', component: MedicalRecordsComponent },
        { path: 'care-plan', component: CarePlanComponent },

Comment: patient detail redirect-

this._Router.navigate(
                    ['/patient-details/' + patientID]
                );

Comment: Try `this._Router.navigate( ['/patient-details/' + patientID, 'patient-dashboard'] );` or you could use an absolute route providing a string to navigateByUrl method `this._Router.navigateByUrl( '/patient-details/' + patientID + '/patient-dashboard' );`

Comment: Note that if patient-details is a subroute of some path like /example/patient-details... you have to provide the entire path from the root in order to use navigateByUrl method